# Android: Animating changes to GridView content

Tags: android

I have a GridView of layouts which can be dynamically added or removed to the grid.

In iOS, the native behavior for GridView items is for the other items in the grid to slide into the place of the removed item, or slide to make room when a new item is added.

However on Android the behavior is just for the changes to instantly pop in on the screen. I tried adding custom animations to each getView() call using some tricks in the GridView's adapter, but that ended up causing some problems seen here:

[Android GridView loading the 0 indexed item in a later index's slot when data set changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845527/android-gridview-loading-the-0-indexed-item-in-a-later-indexs-slot-when-data-se)

I tried having the individual views control the animation instead of the getView() method of the adapter, but the end result was identical.

I also tried using a GridLayoutAnimationController, like this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, R.anim.grid_item_fadein);
GridLayoutAnimationController controller = new GridLayoutAnimationController(animation, .2f, .2f);
mGrid.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

This works on the initial load of all GridView content, but any changes to that content just instantly pop in like it does by default.

I feel like this is a pretty simple feature, and there should be an easier way to do it. The best I've seen from searching online is [a library](https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid) which animates GridView items that swap places in the grid, but that isn't what I'm looking for (in that same library, when you remove an item from the Grid via deletion the same instant effect that I'm trying to avoid occurs).

A common answer on SO I've also seen is "Look at the APIDemos, there are tons of examples." But as far as I can see, there are actually no examples for animating GridView content changes.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What type of animations are you looking to add? Adding the xml property "animateLayoutChanges = true" will provide some basic fluid animations to just about any view.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: May ,I know how to stop this animation.

Answer (score 7):

Chet Haase came out with a nice video on how to handle ListView animations properly. The basic  concept can be applied to GridViews. You can find the video [here](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2013/02/devbytes-listview-animations.html).

If you're developing for API 1.0+, you won't be able to use the referenced animation features that the video mentions (such as [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html)) unless you use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I think for AdapterViews, the LayoutTransition of ViewGroup won't work. Looking at the source code, ViewGroup ensures the transition animations of other children happen for calls to `addView` and `removeView`, but the derived AdapterView doesn't use those methods, since it relies on an adapter for supplying views.

Chet Haase's video mentioned above is about animating a single child view of a ListView that is disappearing, rather than animating all other surrounding child views that move to fill in the gap.

And, if I'm understanding it right, the GridLayoutAnimationController is about staggered animations for the children as they fill in (ie first time or a complete relayout of the whole list, starting from empty), rather than animating in-place layout changes of surrounding children after an add or remove. so, do the children appear by fading in or sliding in or spinning in - always one at a time, from first to last.

Finally, a suggested solution: if you don't need an adapter-based view, you could switch to GridLayout or LinearLayout. That's where `animateLayoutChanges="true"` will work, and what the 'layout animation' demos always use.
Note LayoutTransition requires minimum api level 11. and GridLayout requires api14.

Answer (score 4):

After you have made any changes to the GridView like .remove()
you have to call **mGrid.startLayoutAnimation();**

The GridView won't do it automatically for you. You have to trigger it manually ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I've found this resource link quite helpful for dealing with animation for other layout views such as LinearLayout etc.:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html
Hopefully this can help.
You can also have a look at https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations for inspiration