# Animating of reordering items in GridLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

What is the way to implement animation of reordering items in GridLayout when I add or remove or reorder items in GridLayout?

For example

```
GirdLayout layout = findById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(someView,index);
//and how to make items animated on reordering ?
```

Appreciate your help or ideas!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at the official google docs on animating layout changes](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html), this should work for GridLayout too

Edit: or take a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890847/android-animating-changes-to-gridview-content).

Comment: @AndroidNoob: The question was for GridLayout, & your answer is for GridView. I don't know how it relates.

Comment: This is not an answer, neither answers. 1st is about auto animating all kind of views, other is for GridView, which is not GridLayout.